# Oracle: How to select count by comparing two dates and another one column(2 values)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a newbie in Oracle. I have a question and I have no idea how to query this.
I've got dummy data as below.

```
CustID        Date        Value
==============================
  1         28/04/15        A
  1         21/12/15        B
  2         01/09/15        A
  2         17/08/15        B
  3         10/12/15        B
  4         09/07/15        A
  4         25/12/15        B
```

I want to select count(distinct CustID) where Date is more that 30 days and Value = A. Then if any CustIDs match with the condition one then continue checking, if Date is less than 30 days and Value = B.

Here is my query that I have tried.

```
Select Count(distinct CustID) From Table 
where Date < Sysdate -30 and Value = 'A'
Intersect
Select Count(distinct CustID)
From Table
where Date >= Sysdate -30 and Value = 'B';
```

The output of the query that I want should look like this.

```
Count(CustID)
2
```

In the output, CustID=1's and CustID=4's are returned because they have value A when date is more than 30 days and when date is less than 30 days, they have value B.

Please guide and help me on how to query this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there only 1 value of a group of `CustID` and `Value`. I mean for `CustID=1` and `Value=A`, will you have only 1 value?
Also please mention the Oracle version

Comment: also why `CustID=2`,`date=01/09/15` is not part of your output? The date is older than 30 days.

Comment: I have already edited the query. I was wrong about date. If it is more than 30 days. It should look like "Date < sysdate -30", right? if I understand correctly and the reason why the CustID=2 is not in my output because when value=B, is not less than 30 days. I want to check CustID that exactly match with two conditions. So i don't select this CustID. BTW,Thank you for your time. Hopefully my explanation make you more clear.

Comment: Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494299/5234334) which I gave earlier and if it works for you, accept it by clicking on 'tick` symbol on left of the answer. Happy to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a count of customer ids that meet two conditions:

- `Date > Sysdate - 30 and Value = 'A'`
- `Date <= Sysdate - 30 and Value = 'B'`

If so, here is one method:

```
select count(*)
from (select custid
      from table t
      where (Date > Sysdate - 30 and Value = 'A') or
            (Date <= Sysdate - 30 and Value = 'B')
      group by custid
      having count(distinct value) = 2
     ) t
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but do I have to change the query that if I want date more than 30 days, it should look like "Date< sysdate-30"? and would you mind explaining more why you use 'Or'? Thank you

Comment: @Pizza . . . (1) You would change the "30" to whatever value is appropriate.  (2) The `OR` is needed because the subquery gets records that meet either condition, and the two conditions are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. I swapped the conditions to match your requirements. Also please don't use `value` or `date` as column name as these are oracle reserved keyword. I changed them too.

```
select count(*) from 
(
    Select distinct CustID 
    From Table1 
    where to_date(Date1,'DD/MM/RR') <= Sysdate -30 and Value1 = 'A'
        Intersect
    Select distinct CustID
    From Table1
    where to_date(Date1,'DD/MM/RR') > Sysdate -30 and Value1 = 'B'
)
```

**See demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c7568/9

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not needed here, `INTERSECT` is set operator.

Answer (score 0):

Using exist and not exist seem clear for me and check if conditions are strictly respected:

```
select count (distinct cust_id) from TABLE1 where 
exists (select 1 from table1 t1a where t1a.N_DATE < (sysdate - 30) AND t1a.VAL = 'A' AND t1a.CUST_ID =  TABLE1.cust_id )
and not exists (select 1 from table1 t1b where t1b.N_DATE > (sysdate - 30) AND t1b.VAL = 'A' AND t1b.CUST_ID =  TABLE1.cust_id )
and exists (select 1 from table1 t1c where  t1c.VAL = 'B' AND t1c.CUST_ID =  TABLE1.cust_id AND t1c.N_DATE > (sysdate - 30)  ) 
and not exists (select 1 from table1 t1d where t1d.N_DATE < (sysdate - 30) AND t1d.VAL = 'B' AND t1d.CUST_ID =  TABLE1.cust_id)
;
```

I changed name of table and column to avoid confusion.